# accessing php variables across files

Tags: php

I have a php file with array as a global variable.I wish that the array should be accessed in other php file for further processing.But the thing is the global array variable is undergoing manipulation by a certain function in the first file.I want the updated value for the array variable in second file for further processing.Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a global variable. Rather, assign the variable to a session before moving on to the next page.

Eg:

```
$_SESSION["MyArray"] = $MyArrayVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add everything inside a $_SESSION variabel, I'm not sure what filestructure you use:

```
include('file1.php');
include('file2.php');
```

or a setup where you from file1.php to file2.php.

In the first setup, you can get the settings outside a function/class and then they are available in file2. In the second you have to store them somewhere (cookie, session, database).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion:-)I used sessions.Now its working properly.